# Was it ever standard to pronounce "malinger" to rhyme with "ginger"?

Tags: pronunciation, pronunciation-vs-spelling, historical-change

In *The Pronunciation of Standard English in America,* by George Philip Krapp (1919), I found the following surprising statement:

> For **malinger** the standard pronunciation is [mə´lɪndʒə̉ɹ], though occasionally speakers are led to pronounce the word as though it were a variant form of *linger* [´lɪŋgə̉ɹ].

([p. 131](https://books.google.com/books?id=NcApAAAAYAAJ&pg=PA131#v=onepage&q&f=false); the "ə̉" is a placeholder for a character that I can't find in Unicode; it's like a schwa but the top part is curlier than usual)

I haven't found any other source (from any time period, about any variety of English) that confirms Krapp's description of [məˈlɪndʒəɹ] as "the standard pronunciation" of *malinger*. The 1918 pronunciation guide "[Every-day pronunciation](https://archive.org/details/cu31924027389810/page/n165)", by Robert Palfrey Utter (who lived in America), gives the pronunciation of "malinger" only as "mã̇lĭṇ´gêṛ", which corresponds more or less to IPA [məˈlɪŋgə(ɹ)].

Does anyone have any further information about the variant pronunciation of *malinger* with [dʒ], and why Krapp might have thought of it as the "standard pronunciation" of this word?

Comment: The OED acknowledges only /məˈlɪŋɡə(r)/ - in the online version (entry updated 2000), in the online OED2 (1989), and in my compact edition (dated 1979)

Answer (score 1):

Webster's dictionaries started including detailed pronunciation with the 1864 edition, and it looks like they always identified *malinger* to have a "hard g", rhyming with *linger* ([1864](https://archive.org/details/americandictiona00websuoft/page/805), [1890](https://archive.org/details/webstersinternat00port/page/887), [1930](https://archive.org/details/webstersnewinter00webs/page/1305)). Worcester's dictionaries, however, transcribe it as having a "soft g", rhyming with *ginger* ([1850](https://books.google.co.jp/books?id=ABcPAAAAYAAJ&pg=PA436), [1860](https://archive.org/details/cu31924027443393/page/n949)).

Early British pronouncing dictionaries from the 18th and 19th centuries do not include the word. Daniel Jones seems to have always had it /məˈlɪŋɡə(r)/ ([1913](https://archive.org/details/cu31924027444284/page/n317), [1917](https://archive.org/details/in.ernet.dli.2015.93283/page/n344), [1944](https://archive.org/details/in.ernet.dli.2015.94053/page/n301)), as did Kenyon & Knott ([1944](https://archive.org/details/pronouncingdicti00unse/page/266)).

Given the earliest record of the pronunciation of the consonants in *malinger* I could find was Worcester who had it rhyming with *ginger*, Krapp may be right in saying that that pronunciation preceded the "linger" pronunciation, but it seems to have only persisted until around the turn of the century, if not earlier.